# Case when not selected refactoring

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

It's Rails/Ruby. Just wondering if there is a DRYer version to remove the repetition in the following code:

```
case params[:order]
when 'rating_ascend'
  order = {:order => 'rating_average ASC'}
when 'rating_descend'
  order = {:order => 'rating_average DESC'}
when 'distance'
  order = {:order => 'distance ASC'}
else
  order = {:order => 'distance ASC'}
end
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Or course, there is.

```
order = case params[:order]
  when 'rating_ascend'
    {:order => 'rating_average ASC'}
  when 'rating_descend'
    {:order => 'rating_average DESC'}
  else
    {:order => 'distance ASC'}
end
```

Or even this (I wouldn't write like this, but this is DRYer)

```
order = {:order => case params[:order]
  when 'rating_ascend' then 'rating_average ASC'
  when 'rating_descend' then 'rating_average DESC'
  else 'distance ASC'
end}
```

When you simplify code to this point, you notice that you have double "distance ASC" result. Is it a typo or intentional?

Comment: Actually I just intended to not duplicate the `distance ASC`, but you guys refactored even more... No, it's not a type. This `order` is an optional parameter.

Comment: Why wouldn't you write the second method usually?

Comment: I find it messy. This is how I'd write it (with temp variable): http://pastie.org/4449688

Comment: Thanks. Learnt something today.

Answer (score 3):

```
order = {}
order[:order] = case params[:order]
when "rating_ascend" then "rating_average ASC"
when "rating_descend" then "rating_average DESC"
else "distance ASC"
end
```

Comment: I like it better than semicolon.

Comment: Thanks. Learnt something today.

Answer (score 3):

```
orders = {'rating_ascend' =>  'rating_average ASC', 'rating_descend' => 'rating_average DESC', 'distance' => 'distance ASC'}
Model.order(orders[params[:order]] || 'distance ASC')
```

Comment: Thanks. Learnt something today.

Answer (score 2):

Using the 'extract method' refactoring pattern:

```
def determine_order(order)
  case order
  when 'rating_ascend'
    'rating_average ASC'
  when 'rating_descend'
    'rating_average DESC'
  else
    'distance ASC'
end

order = {:order => determine_order(params[:order])}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like the previous answer, even to make it better just remove the unwanted case

```
  when 'distance'
    'distance ASC'
```

since the else part will perform the same.

```
order = {:order => case params[:order]
  when 'rating_ascend'
    'rating_average ASC'
  when 'rating_descend'
    'rating_average DESC'
  else
    'distance ASC'
end}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about creating the hash with the diferent options and using fetch to find the option, something like :

```
order = order_hash.fetch(params[:order], {:order => 'distance ASC'})

def order_hash
  {
    'rating_ascend' => {:order => 'rating_average ASC'},
    'rating_descend' => {:order => 'rating_average DESC'},
    'distance' => {:order => 'distance ASC'}
  }
end
```

And because fetch can take a default option as a second params you can easily solve the else problem at the end of your case.